# Can't unmount drive without killing bash

Tags: bash, usb-drive, unmounting

I don't know whether its normal or not but when I mount a filesystem(ext4 partition, USB, SD card etc) via command line, I can't unmount it because it says 
`target is busy`

It is the bash process which is using/accessing it.
So I have to kill it first and then only can unmount the drive. As you have guessed, when I kill the bash process the terminal shuts down.and I have to reopen the terminal  and unmount the drive.
Is it normal ? I don't remember it happening the last time I unmounted something.

Comment: If you `cd` into the mountpoint, it will be openend by `bash` so of course it will be busy.  `cd $HOME` and then try to unmount, or use `sudo fuser /mount/point` to figure out what else is using the process

Comment: I am using fuser to detect the PID and than look it up in TOP (let me know if there's is any short cut rather than running top to identify the process). Let me just try mount and unmount in quick succession without touching anything else. BRB

Comment: Well, not sure if it's shortcuts but I'd use `ps -p 1234 -o args` where 1234 is pid, or just examine `/proc/1234/cmdline`

Comment: thanks for the short cut and yap you are right, it most probably was me cding into the mounted drive and could recollect a thing what I was doing. whew that's was quick.

Comment: Alright, I'll make it a proper answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `cd` into the mountpoint, it will be openend by bash so of course it will be busy. `cd $HOME` and then try to unmount. Otherwise use `sudo fuser /mount/point` to figure out what else is using the mountpoint or files within it.

<sub>source: doing exactly the same mistake and learning from it</sub>